# Spring SwitchUserFilter with Active Directory authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, active-directory

I have set up authentication with Active Directory like this:

```
AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryAuthenticationProvider(UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper) {

ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
    "company.local",
    "ldap://active-directory-dc:389");
provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper);
return provider;
```

I would like to use `SwitchUserFilter` for users impersonation. However, I can see only method `SwitchUserFilter#setUserDetailsService` to set up authentication object and it's not possible to pass `AuthenticationProvider` to the filter. Alternatively, I don't know if (and how) is possible to use `UserDetailsService` for authentication with Active Directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by implementing my own `UserDetailsService` which searches LDAP for user names. Alternatively, it is possible to use `LdapUserDetailsService` (if you don't need significant customization).